# AS3 remove extension from var

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I believe this is a simple question. How can I remove the ".mp3" extension in the var name?

```
import flash.filesystem.File;
var desktop:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("Music");
var files:Array = desktop.getDirectoryListing();
for (var i:uint = 0; i < files.length; i++)
{

 var myVar = files[i].name;// gets file name. 
}


trace(myVar); // comes out "mySong.mp3"
```

Should I use a split or remove the last 3 characters? What is the best method to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, I would think split would work best.  This way you could use the same method no matter what type of file you are pulling.

`var myVar = files[i].name.split('.')[0];`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this. Check the docs for more

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String

You could use split with indexOf

```
//substr(startIndex:Number = 0, len:Number = 0x7fffffff):String
//use indexOf to get the index of the first .
//return from 0 to that index
var myVar:String = files[i].name.split(0, files[i].name.indexOf("."));
```

Comment: Thanks for the great comment. I gave you a plus one. I tried your code but it came out with the .mp3 when I called it. The answer above worked so I gave them the check. Again I do appreciate your effort. Thanks so much.